# document.write() style position after load

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, document.write

I have three php file that can be recalled by **document.write()** ... But their 'div Style' place is in the chaotic format. I want to take them on a regular basis...

**file1.php** with 120*240 pixel :

```
document.write('
<?php 
//some PHP codes
//echo style
echo"<style>#ps2{height:240;width:120;line-height:12px;font-family:tahoma;}
p a{text-decoration:none;}</style>";
echo("<div id=\"ps2\">");
//some PHP codes
echo"</div>";
?>
');
```

Calling php file :

```
<script language="javascript" src="file1.php"></script>
```

if i call **file2.php** with 468*60 pixel and **file3.php** with125*125 pixel in the same page , how can i fix all codes displayed separately and regular.

- And displayed in any page separately and regular not only in a specific page with specific css... thanks

Comment: What is that you want to accomplish?

Comment: If you have problems with english show images of what you want and what you get instead.

Comment: What does in chaotic format mean? Also... I can understand why you want to use PHP to make the page have adjustable styles (but there are better ways that would require understanding your uses cases better)... but having PHP return javascript that generates the CSS is a strong anti-pattern... why not have the php file return the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're loading the files via http, it's easy enough to have

html:

```
<script src="file.php?x=468&y=60"></script>
```

file.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/javascript');

$html = <<<EOL
<style>
#ps2 {
   width: {$_GET['x']},
   height: {$_GET['y']}, etc....
EOL;
?>
document.write(<?php echo(json_encode($html)); ?>);
```

?>